# Does Clojure's core.async work with RoboVM?

Tags: clojure, robovm, core.async

I've used [lein-fruit](https://github.com/oakes/lein-fruit) to generate a basic Clojure project that targets iOS through [RoboVM](http://www.robovm.org/). I've introduced core.async to pass button taps along a channel, but mutating the button in the `go` block doesn't seem to have an effect.

Is there reason to believe the Java implementation of core.async doesn't work under RoboVM?

Here's my code, slightly modified from the basic lein-fruit template.

```lisp
(ns core-async-demo.core
  (:require [core-async-demo.core-utils :as u]
            [clojure.core.async :refer [go chan put! <!]]))

(def window (atom nil))

(def taps (chan))

(defn init
  []
  (let [main-screen (u/static-method :uikit.UIScreen :getMainScreen)
        button-type (u/static-field :uikit.UIButtonType :RoundedRect)
        button (u/static-method :uikit.UIButton :fromType button-type)
        normal-state (u/static-field :uikit.UIControlState :Normal)
        click-count (atom 0)]
    (doto button
      (.setFrame (u/init-class :coregraphics.CGRect 115 121 91 37))
      (.setTitle "Click me!" normal-state)
      (.addOnTouchUpInsideListener
        (proxy [org.robovm.cocoatouch.uikit.UIControl$OnTouchUpInsideListener] []
          (onTouchUpInside [control event]
            (put! taps true)))))
    (reset! window (u/init-class :uikit.UIWindow (.getBounds main-screen)))
    (go
      (loop [_ (<! taps)]
        (.setTitle button (str "Click #" (swap! click-count inc)) normal-state)
        (recur (<! taps))))
    (doto @window
      (.setBackgroundColor (u/static-method :uikit.UIColor :lightGrayColor))
      (.addSubview button)
      .makeKeyAndVisible)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about core.async on RoboVM specifically, but background threads in general are not supposed to interact with UIKit. It's a documented limitation of the framework. I would try something simpler to test out core.async on RoboVM and, if it works, you should be able to [use Grand Central Dispatch](http://blog.robovm.org/2013/08/support-for-objective-c-blocks.html) to run your code on the main queue.

Comment: I'm curious as to the result of this. Is core.async in general something translatable thru robovm and runnable on ios?